# got No instructions provided while doing Liquidity.computeAmountOut

Tags: swap

im trying to create pool and right after that perform swap. im getting No instructions provided while doing Liquidity.computeAmountOut. here is my code snippet

```
 const poolKeys = Liquidity.getAssociatedPoolKeys({
    marketId,
    baseMint: baseToken,
    quoteMint:quoteToken,
    baseDecimals: 6,
    quoteDecimals: 9,
    programId: PROGRAMIDS.AmmV4,
    marketProgramId: PROGRAMIDS.OPENBOOK_MARKET,
});
console.log("associatedPoolKeys:", poolKeys);
const { amountOut, minAmountOut } = Liquidity.computeAmountOut({
    poolKeys: poolKeys,
    poolInfo: await Liquidity.fetchInfo({ connection, poolKeys }),
    amountIn: 1000,
    currencyOut: quoteToken,
    slippage: 1,
})
```